# Different behavior between devtools::test and sourcing tests, involving Rcpp

Tags: r, devtools, cgal, testthat

I'm currently working on a package which implements the lazy numbers of the C++ library **CGAL** in R.

In particular, the `NaN` lazy number is implemented as `lazyNumber(0) / lazyNumber(0)`.

I have no problem with this implementation, except with unit tests. Indeed, I have this unit test:

```r
test_that("lazy vector with NA, NaN, and Inf values", {
  nv <- c(1, NA, NaN, Inf, -Inf)
  lv <- lazyvec(nv)
  expect_length(lv, 5L)
})
```

When I run this code, no problem. But when running this test with the button in RStudio, which executes `devtools::test()`, I get a C++ error: the **CGAL** library complains that a division by 0 is performed:

```
<CGAL::Precondition_exception/C++Error/error/condition>
Error in `nv2lvx(x)`: CGAL ERROR: precondition violation!
Expr: b != 0
File: /home/stla/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/RcppCGAL/include/CGAL/Lazy_exact_nt.h
Line: 679
```

How is it possible? Is there a difference when directly sourcing some code vs sourcing it via `devtools::test`, when C++ is involved?

Comment: I think you should swap the `Rcpp` tag for the `devtools` tag.  If you use `Rcpp` with the functions we document (_i.e._ plain old `R CMD build ...` and `R CMD check ...`) you likely have fewer surprises as fewer _additional_ settings are enabled. `devtools` does what it does for a reason and many people, you included, find it helpful.  However, it makes things _more_ opaque.  So pick your poison.  All this has AFAICR been discussed before but as a non-`devtools` user I don't pay too much attention.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Ok. But `devtools` or `testthat` does not rebuild the package. The same DLL is used so how is it possible? No idea?

Comment: But they set a number of environment variable which control behavior, alter paths, ...  It is (usually) possible to demonstrate that `Rcpp` alone (using the `R CMD ...` entry points only) behaves as expected.  So you are shooting at a messenger, you could also shoot at `make` or `gcc` or `R` but methinks you should start at the top.  And simplify.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel It seems to work now. Previously the package was built with `devtools::install(quick = TRUE)`. Now I've built it with `R CMD install`.

Comment: Well I have been on the record before (as has _e.g._ Uwe Ligges of the CRAN team on the r-package-devel list) that in case of issue you should move away from helper such as `devtools` who are known to have exhibited side-effects. You just extended that exhibition by one.  So maybe close / delete the (non-)question?

Comment: Or put your own answer in detailing a) where and how it went wrong and b) where and how it worked.  Given that SO has decent Google standings that may help someone someday.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, sometimes the error also occured when the code was ordinarily sourced.

I think this error was due to the fact that the package was installed with `devtools::install(quick = TRUE, keep_source = TRUE)`. Indeed, now it seems that the error does not occur anymore, after I reinstalled the package with the button in RStudio, which runs `R CMD install`.